# How to set a Java bean property as an expert property?

Tags: java, swing, javabeans, introspection

The Java Beans Introspection API includes in the `PropertyDescriptor` class the method `isExpert`.  Bean-based GUI editors, like WindowsMaker, use this to hide or show "exotic" properties.

What causes a certain property of a Java bean to be considered "expert"?  How does the Swing library, for example, sets certain properties as "expert properties"?  How can I programmatically do the same for Java beans that I write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [BeanInfo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) class for your bean. This allows you to customize the property descriptor. There is a section covering this in the [JavaBean tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Beans/Beans4/nervous06.html).

Answer (score 2):

This apparently is done in the JDK using a non-standard compiler extension.

If you have a look at the Swing source code, some Javadoc comments include a `@beaninfo` tag, containing such information:

```
/**
 * ... Some comment ...
 * @beaninfo
 *        bound: true
 *       expert: true
 */
public void setSomething(SomeType value) {
    // ...
}
```

Here is an example, in the [JTable class source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/swing/jdk/file/6c9c55ae313b/src/share/classes/javax/swing/JTable.java).

I also found [this article](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch07_03.htm), talking about the `@beaninfo` tag.